# Implode and form data

Tags: php, mysql

Got a small problem regarding saving my form to the database and imploding. The issue is as following:

I have a form which has multiple fields, including checkboxes, which has an array of values. If I send the whole form to my php script it strips the checkbox value with the last one checked, so the issue is, I only get the last checked value in my database instead of all the checked values.

So I did a bit of debugging and I found the issue, it's in this line:

```
$values  =  "'" . implode("', '", $_POST) . "'";
```

This strips my data unfortunately.

EDIT:

This is my PHP script:

```
$hoeveelheidvalues = count($_POST);


$values  =  "'" . implode("', '", $_POST) . "'";
$queryvoorderesperform = "INSERT INTO `app_res_per_form` (";

for($i = 1; $i <= $hoeveelheidvalues; $i++)
{
    if($i==$hoeveelheidvalues)
    {
        $queryvoorderesperform .= "vraag$i";
    }
    else{
        $queryvoorderesperform .= "vraag$i, ";
    }

}

$queryvoorderesperform .= ") VALUES ($values)";
```

EDIT 2:

If I use serialize I get a very weird string. This is the $queryvoorderespform:

```
INSERT INTO `app_res_per_form` (vraag1, vraag2, vraag3, vraag4, vraag5, vraag6, vraag7, vraag8, vraag9, vraag10, vraag11, vraag12) 
VALUES (a:12:{s:16:"multipleradios-0";s:11:"Orientation";s:11:"textinput-0";s:0:"";s:20:"multiplecheckboxes-0";s:9:"Recycling";s:11:"textinput-1";s:0:"";s:10:"interestin";s:15:"Diverter Valves";s:12:"rotaryvalves";s:7:"AL, AXL";s:14:"divertervalves";s:3:"PTD";s:15:"othercomponents";s:3:"DUC";s:11:"textinput-3";s:0:"";s:16:"multipleradios-1";s:18:"Systems Integrator";s:16:"multipleradios-2";s:38:"Will buy product in long time (1 year)";s:15:"standcrewmember";s:13:"Aap";})
```

Comment: checking for errors would signal syntax errors. no idea which MySQL API you're using to connect/query with.

Comment: There has to be 100 better ways of doing this, and by the way where is your sanity checking on the values in your $_POST array

Comment: There are 100000 ways of doing this better. At the moment I need to make this work, it's a temporary solution though.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Obviously [my comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30734011/implode-and-form-data#comment49525826_30734011) to the OP means either nothing and they feel it's irrelevant, or they have no idea what I'm talking about.

Comment: `VALUES (a:12:{s:16:"multipleradios-0";` does this look like something MySQL won't complain about? [This comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30734011/implode-and-form-data#comment49525826_30734011) hasn't been responded to. How are we to help you and give you the right error checking method if we don't know this.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Look at EDIT2 and you will see what they are really trying to do. Its not a mysql issue more a how to build a string issue.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I did see edit #2, but those need to be quoted; that should have thrown them a syntax error from the get go. I like giving OP's error checking methods, but their API is unknown, so I didn't give them multiple choices.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I was only meaning that the question probably didn't warrant your further attention!

Comment: @RiggsFolly I'm outta here then. Good luck with the question, I honestly wish you well. Edit: Tab closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `serialize()`, its a PHP function to convert an array or object  into a string that can then be re-hydrated back into an array or object using `unserialize();`

$values = serialize($_POST);

or better still save the contents of $_POST as JSON using

```
$values = json_encode($_POST);
```

and re-hydrate into an array or object using

```
$var = json_decode($x);
```

These can be used on PHP Arrays or PHP Objects.

**Ok now I see what you are actually trying to do** so try this :-

```
$fields = '';
$values = '';
$count = 0;

foreach ( $_POST as $idx => $val ) {
    // I assume you are skipping occurance 0 for a reason
    if ( $count == 0 ) { 
       $count++;
       continue; 
    }

    $fields .= sprintf('vraag%d,', $count );
    $values .= sprintf("'%s',", $val );

    $count++;
}
//trim off trailing commas
rtrim($fields, ',');
rtrim($values, ',');

$sql = sprintf('INSERT INTO `app_res_per_form` (%s) VALUES (%s)',
               $fields, $values); 

}
```

Oh and I assume you are using the MYSQL_ extension! Someone is going to tell you not to and to switch to MYSQLI_ or PDO. So it may as well be me.

Comment: See above, I made an edit. It's dynamic saving into the database, so I don't think I can use the serialize.

Comment: Is this just that you didnt remember that the browser only sends CHECKED checkboxes to the PHP Script, and ignores the unchecked ones.

Comment: I need to test some things out. Thanks for the answer! If I fix it I'll make sure that anyone knows what the solution was and I mark your answer as right!

Comment: Ok this wasn't the answer. If I serialize the POST array I get this: SEE EDIT ABOVE

Comment: See my attempt at an answer now you have explained exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was trying to do.